# ClassCastException in findViewById while using custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using custom TextView. But when I am retrieving it using find view by Id I get ClassCastException. I have using it in XML file like this:

`<View class="com.android.smsapp.MsgTextView" 
        android:id="@+id/text"`

And using it in java file like this.

`MsgTextView  text = (MsgTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);`

What am I doing wrong?

---

@Pavandroid

I have included it in correct file

```
    package com.android.smsapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MsgTextView extends TextView {
    private String sender;

    MsgTextView(Context c){
        super(c);
    }

    MsgTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    MsgTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setSender(String s) {
        sender = s;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return (sender);
    }
}`
```

Also When I checked properly, LogCat is showing one more line

```
03-19 14:30:41.476: E/AndroidRuntime(24089): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MsgTextView(Context,AttributeSet).. But I have defined this constructor.
```

Comment: just usee com.android.smsapp.MsgTextView instead of textview in the xml part and make sure your class MsgTextView extends textview

Answer (score 1):

instead of the above code use the below code.

```
<com.android.smsapp.MsgTextView 
          android:id="@+id/text"
          additional parameters here....>
</com.android.smsapp.MsgTextView>
```

Comment: Tried it .. But now I am getting "03-19 13:03:30.632: E/AndroidRuntime(22775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.smsapp/com.android.smsapp.SMSAppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.android.smsapp.MsgTextView"

Comment: Do you place the MsgTextView in the proper package i.e., com.android.smsapp ?? Please cross check this and try again ....

Comment: Still getting the issue ... Everything looks fine ... Have pasted MsgTextView class